# Speex encode in terminal MAC OS but command not found

Tags: macos, audio, encode, speex

I want to convert spx file to WAV file use speexdec command in MAC terminal. `find OtherResources -name "*.spx" -execdir sh -c 'spx={};speexdec $spx  ${spx%.*}.wav' \` and got `sh: speexdec: command not found` I used Macports to install speex `sudo port install speex`.  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that both homebrew and Macports install speex doesn't solove this problem on Mac.
You should build speex from source code .

Follow these steps :

1. Download source code from [here](https://www.speex.org/downloads/)
2. Open terminal in source code folder
3. ./configure
4. make
5. sudo make install
6. Then run your convert command.

PS: You can find this problem in [pyglossary issue](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/issues/184#issuecomment-586160635)